# Is there a risk that cold storage wallets containing non RingCT outputs will be unspendable in the future?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, hard-fork, wallet-recovery

If I fund a wallet today and don't touch it for 5 years, is there a risk that I won't be able to spend my funds? Is it advisable to move funds around to a new wallet with each hard fork?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Theres no need to move arround your funds after any fork, even with updates like min mixing and the future RingCT the transactions will allways be compatible with the old ones

Answer (score 9):

Despite the hard fork in March, 2016, setting a minimum mixin and effectively banning dust outputs (except as part of the coinbase, which is further going to change in the September, 2016, hard fork) we provided a "catch" that let users sweep their dust outputs at a mixin of 0. This functionality will be supported indefinitely, because maybe in a few years your 0.018293791 dust output is actually worth a couple of USD.

Similarly, any hard fork functionality in the future will have to, by necessity, provide a way for very old outputs to be spent indefinitely. We can and will deprecate APIs and client-side functionality, but we'd never prevent people from spending their own money.